# Access 2010: Count and Distinct Count in same query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on a query in Access 2010 that is intended to aggregate the number of projects and project tasks a person has completed.

For example:

```
Person    |    Project    |    Project Task
1                1                1
1                1                2
1                2                1
2                1                1
2                1                2
```

I would like it to return:

```
Person    |    Project(s)    |    Project Task(s)
1                 2                  3
2                 1                  2
Total             3                  5
```

As it stands my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT Person, Project, Count(Project Task) AS Project Task
FROM table 
GROUP BY Person, Project
ORDER BY Person;
```

Which returns:

```
Person    |    Project    |    Project Task(s)
1                 1                  2
1                 2                  1
2                 1                  2
Total             3                  5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select person, count(project), sum(projectTask) from 
(
    select person,  project, count(projectTask) as projectTask
    from table
    group by person, project
)
group by person   
order by person
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.